# Typescript Angular How to add inner class

Tags: angular, typescript

Hi here i have a class as

```js
export class Employeemodel {
    constructor() {
        this.name = "";
        this.gender = 0;
    }
    name: string;
    gender: number;
}
```

When i try to Bind data to This Class as

```js
// EmployeeService.ts

GetData<T>(pagenum:number) {
    return this
        .http
        .get<Employeemodel[]>(this.apiUrl+'GetPagination/'+pagenum)
        .pipe(tap(data => {
            
        }));
}
```

```js
// EmployeeComponent.ts
 
GetPagination(PageNo: number) {
    this._oservices
        .GetData(PageNo)
        .subscribe((result: Employeemodel[]) => {
            this.dataSource = new MatTableDataSource(result.otestgrid);   
        });
}
```

**result.otestgrid** Getting Error as  Property '**otestgrid' does not exist on type 'Employeemodel[]'.**

My Service call Giving Me output as

```
{
    "otestgrid": [
        {
            "name": "Dastageer",
            "gender": 1,
            "distName": "Hyderabad",
            "otestBindata": null
        },
}
```

Comment: can you please share `this._oservices.GetData(PageNo)` function in your question

Comment: @AshotAleqsanyan Just Now i Update my Question Please Go

Comment: your'e saying to typescript that the response if of type Employeemodel[], that's the reason you has an error. you can use `subscribe((res:any)=> {..}` or create an interface with the model of the response

Comment: @Eliseo  Could you Please Help me how can i Create it from an Interface

Answer (score 1, accepted):

your `Employeemodel` should be realized like this, Also I recommend in cammel case

```js
export class EmployeeModel {
  "name": string;
  "gender": number;
  "distName"?: string;    // if it should be optional you can add `?`
  "otestBindata"?: unknown // unknown since I don't know what is the type, you can change
}
```

and actually, your response type is `{ otestgrid: EmployeeModel[] }` if you didn't transform the data after getting the response.

so your function in the service should look like this

```
GetData(pagenum:number){
    return this.http
       .get<{ otestgrid: EmployeeModel[] }>(
          this.apiUrl+'GetPagination/'+pagenum
       ).pipe(tap(data=>{}));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

an [interface](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/objects.html) it's only write

```
public interface DataResponse{
  otestgrid: EmployedData[]
}
public interface EmployedData{
{
 name:string;
 gender:number;
 distName:string;
 otestBindata": any;
}
```

See that, if we are not thinking about create a method, it's better use interface that class.

Remember that Angular "transpile" typescript  (convert typescript to javascript) so the only that we are making using "typed variables" are help **us** to write code. Some like

```
this.http.get<{ otestgrid: EmployeeModel[] }>(...)
```

**not** sure that we received a response of type indicate, and don't transform the response. The response will be the response to the call -imagine you miss and indicate another call, Angular can not take account this